# How to display sum of row data in view using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view. How can I calculate sum of rows using view without using model and controller

```
foreach($requests as $request):
<?php echo SUM($request->unit_price) ?>
<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: The whole point of MVC is you don't do business logic like this in the view, where possible. And `sum()` takes an array; you're feeding (what I presume to be) a number.

Comment: use SUM in your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($requests as $request):
    $sum += $request->unit_price;
endforeach;
echo $sum;
```

Comment: displays two values and its iterating

Comment: What do you mean by `displays two values`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Melebius : I will defiantly write that but this is so simple and short code.

Comment: @Melebius Thanks very much Its working, i have accepted your answer

Comment: @turaco : answer given by me "urfusion" not by "melebius. "
anyway glad to know its working.

Comment: oh sorry @urfusion i didnt  identify you , my badness, good guy thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($requests as $request){
$data[]=$request->unit_price;
}
```

now `$data` array contains all the unit prices.

```
echo array_sum($data);
```

and you get your answer.